# avoid loading all data from tables into context in EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first

I am  totally new to EF Code First approach and i am stuck in a few troubles.I really need your help pls..

I have 3 classes like below

```
 [Table("Customers")] 
public class Customer
{

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string FirmName { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<CustomerEmail> CustomerEmails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }




}

 [Table("CustomerEmail")]
public class CustomerEmail
{

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime RecordTime { get; set; }


    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

 [Table("CustomerAddress")]
public class CustomerAddress
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Int16 CountryCode { get; set; }
    public Int16 CityCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }


    public virtual  Customer Customer { get; set; }


}


 public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerEmail> CustomerEmails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }

}
```

My Problems

1)
When i run the app it can not find related tables to customer which are CustomerAddress and CustomerEmail.It gives an error saying "Customer_Id   not exits in CustomerEmail and CustomerAddress tables".I think something  wrong  on relations between these models.I need your helps to improve these relations.

2)There is no problem on getting  customer data .But it brings all data .for example i have 10.0000 rows in customer table and it brings 10.000 rows into my context class .This is not good.i dont want it to bring all data at first .i want to bring just related data when i query.

Guys i really need your help soon .Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

1. Due you are not following the EF foreign key conventions, you will need to set those relations by fluent-mapping into your DbContext class. Look for a blog about fluent-mapping to figureout how to make one-to-one relations
2. Maybe you are performing a linq query without a where clause. Please put some code related with this item.

Comment: Kayhan, actually when you try to check any DbSet in your DbContext object, using a Watch by example, EF performs a query against the database to get all rows. So, it is not happen when you initialize your context, but when you access your DbSet whitout where clausule. If you build a query by using linq or extensions methods this not happen. Try something like this: context.Customers.Where(c => c.ShortName == "Kayhan"). EF will perform a filtered query. In sumary, your rows are not been loaded when you initialize your context. No worries.

Comment: Kayhan, try this:  modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerAddresses>()
        .HasKey(a => a.Id)
        .HasRequired(a => a.Customer)
        .WithMany(b => b.CustomerAddresses)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.CustomerId);

Comment: it didnt work.it is still the same result one row.when i check the profiler it produce correct script but in entity it is one row

Answer (score 1):

```
[Table("CustomerAddress")]                     
public class CustomerAddress                     
{                         
public long Id { get; set; }  
public long CustomerId { get; set; }                         
public Int16 CountryCode { get; set; }                          
public Int16 CityCode { get; set; }                          
public string City { get; set; }                         
public string Town { get; set; }                         
public string District { get; set; }                          
public string Street { get; set; }                          
public string PostalCode { get; set; }                                                                      
public virtual  Customer Customer { get; set; 
}


 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {


        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerAddresses>()
        .HasKey(a => a.CustomerId)
        .HasRequired(a => a.Customer)
        .WithMany(b => b.CustomerAddresses)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.Id);        
    }
```

when i query  like   context.Customers.Find(3);

there should be 2 rows  in the CustomerAddresses property of Customer but there is only one row which is the first.Why does it bring only one row?i tried to make 1-n relation